# SpriteKit - how do I apply a constant velocity and change on touch - swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

How do I make my player move left/right at a constant speed until the user touches the screen again, which will then make the player change direction right/left and run that way at a constant speed etc..

I have tried looking at other answers but can't figure out a working answer.

I've set linearDamping to 0 already.

Comment: where is your MVE ? Welcome to SO. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and **[Minimal, complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**, then `edit` your question to community guidelines. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried 1. changing the sprite's velocity or 2. applying a force?

Answer (score 1):

There are two basic ways to apply velocity.

One is by applying forces to physics bodies, or giving them velocities.

Two is positional transformations, usually done with SKActions.

They're not compatible.

Since you're using physics, you need to either [apply force](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1520430-applyforce) or [set a velocity](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1519635-velocity).

I think you should probably take the time to read this entire page:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody

Here's the setting velocity cherry from it:

> First, you can control a physics body’s velocity directly, by setting
>   its velocity and angularVelocity properties. As with many other
>   properties, you often set these properties once when the physics body
>   is first created and then let the physics simulation adjust them as
>   necessary.

And here's the outline on forces:

> You can apply a force to a body in one of three ways: A linear force
>   that only affects the body’s linear velocity. An angular force that
>   only affects the body’s angular velocity. A force applied to a point
>   on the body. The physics simulation calculates separate changes to the
>   body’s angular and linear velocity, based on the shape of the object
>   and the point where the force was applied.